# Best way to create millions of relationships for existing nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have an existing graph with about 1.5mln nodes with label Foo. Each Foo node has a property prop1, which is from a significantly smaller subset (a few thousand values). We now need to be able to traverse the graph using this property (it will be connected to other labels too), and we'd like to convert it into nodes (rather than property).

So basically, if I have

```
 Foo1{prop1:1}
 Foo2{prop1:2} 
 Foo3{prop1:1}
```

then I'd like to create 2 new nodes, Prop1{id:1} and Prop1{id:2}, and link them with a new relationship PROP1.

```
Foo1 -[:PROP1]-> Prop1{id:1}
Foo2 -[:PROP1]-> Prop1{id:2}
Foo3 -[:PROP1]-> Prop1{id:1}
```

I hope it makes sense.

The fundamental problem is that since it's 1.5mln nodes, trying to do it in one go simply runs OOM. 
I managed to come up with a cypher query that generally does small parts of it (I might have messed up something with the syntax as I'm writing from memory, but that was roughly how it worked):

```
MATCH (n:Foo) WHERE NOT(n-[:PROP1]->()) 
WITH n LIMIT 10000
MERGE (p:Prop1 {id = n.prop1}) 
MERGE (n) -[:PROP1] -> (p)
```

Unfortunately running it manually over and over again is a rather boring task ;) so I'm looking for
1) either way to loop it until it's finished (but commits in between parts) OR
2) some other way to execute this in smaller chunks.

Any hints anybody?

Comment: How are you trying to do this in one query?  That's probably the right approach.  If you're running out of memory the way you're formulating that query may be problematic.  You might want to post it.

Comment: If I run it in a single query it's just without the limit, MATCH (n:Foo) WHERE NOT(n-[:PROP1]->()) MERGE (p:Prop1 {id = n.prop1}) MERGE (n) -[:PROP1] -> (p) - it keeps running and running and running... and in the logs I just see GC overhead messages. I also tried on an untouched backup, without the WHERE clause (as I knew no relationships existed) and it had same problem. When I do that for a small subset it works fine, so either I need to have much, much more patience (it was running for quite a few minutes before I killed it), or I need to split it into chunks...

Comment: I'm sorry I can't copy the actual exact query - it's for a client and unfortunately absolutely everything there is top secret and can't be copy-pasted (yes, that REALLY helps solving issues ;) ) :/

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run a slightly different but simple bulk query:

```
MERGE (prop1:Prop1 { id: 1 })
WITH prop1
MATCH (f:Foo { prop1: 1 })
MERGE (f)-[:PROP1]->(prop1)
RETURN count(f);
```

Note that if you `MERGE` the relationship between two nodes, you shouldn't really need the `OPTIONAL MATCH` bit you're doing.

Comment: Well, that only solves the problem partially - first, there are thousands of values for prop1 (so I need to execute it with 1, 2, 20, 5000... - except they are not actually sequential numbers but simply some sort of identifier). I wanted to look them up by checking what is actually referenced from Foos. When I was at work I run the match (f:Foo) merge (p:Prop1 {id : f.prop1}) merge (f) -[:PROP1]-> (p) and it completed after about 20 mins - but only created 600k relationships (the rest was already there, as I was running it batched with LIMITs the day before and these relationships stayed).

Comment: Then I tried doing the same on a similar another property - and it never completed (after about 2 hours I gave up). So... it seems the query itself is okay, but it is simply too much for it to take in one go - so I'm looking what is the best way to chop it into chunks. Is there some kind of equivalent of periodic commit as exists for CSV import?

Comment: Are you indexing your nodes?

Comment: Foos are indexed on their id, but not on that property - since I expect to run through pretty much all of the nodes I didn't think that was useful - do you think it would help? I can try adding an index on prop1 (well, prop2 now :) ) tomorrow and see if that helps.

Comment: Or did you mean adding indexing on Prop1 label ?

Comment: Indexing anything that is mentioned in a `match` is going to help.